# Second dominate phenomenon to effect the speed of time?

Tags: time, spacetime-dimensions

Part of Einstein's Theory Of Relativity is that the faster an object and/or person moves through space, the slower they move through time.

What other phenomenon could potentially effect the passage of time?

While I can't verbally articulate my thoughts as well as a trained scientist I have spent the time to come up with some concepts:

- The effects of traveling through space folded like a(n instant-travel) portal.
- The effects of traveling through a loop of folds in space.
- Additional dimensions beyond the fourth dimension.
- Relative position with respect to combinations such as frequency, physical material (not just baryonic matter), etc.

Comment: Dont forget gravity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation